# Can the moderators please delete my question?

Tags: support, specific-question

I had asked this question a while back..

How do I express a black person?

Altough I might have sounded pedantic, something had happened in real life which had triggered that question.

Now I am feeling that I myself am sounding abusive.

Can this question be deleated?

Alternately can it be edited in a way that it sounds acceptable and let me be known what answer to choose.

I chose that answer in few hours of asking, I was not aware it will have so many answers and might attract attention.

I prefer getting it deleated, kindly delete it.

Due apologies everyone.

Edit: I tried deleating it myself but it is asking for a vote I didnt wanted to attract further attention. So requesting to moderators.

Comment: By the way: you can change the accepted answer whenever you want and how often you want.

Comment: I would request to delete.

Comment: Just thought I'd point out: you asked your question in good faith. You got answers that were helpful to you. Your questions received many upvotes, suggesting it was a good question. You then learned, perhaps from the answers, that you could have treated the whole thing better. Don't you think others might need a similar learning experience? Why would you deprive them of it, by depriving them of the question and its answers? We would not be happy if we have to write those same answers all over again for the next person who will ask the exact same question (which is quite likely to happen).

Comment: Dear Sir, thank you so much for reply. I don't disagree with you nor will I counter-argue . Life has ways to teach lessons, I learnt it in hard way. Hope you understand me. Regards.

Comment: I hit upvote, not to recommend the deletion, but just to thank you for asking a tough question!

Comment: "Alternately can it be edited in a way that it sounds acceptable" it was perfectly acceptable right from the start. Nothing at all abusive about it, at least not that I can see. What is there that *you* perceive as abusive? "Let me be known what answer to choose" - whichever answer helped *you* most. It's a mark of a good question that it received multiple good answers. You don't need to feel overwhelmed by people trying to help you. :) (And who's this "dear sir" you're talking to? I'm A. a girl, B. not a lady. :) )

Comment: I downvoted to express that I don't want to see the question deleted. But I wanted to comment that I respect the way with which you are attempting to make this happen. I hope you manage to resolve this in a way that works for you and the community.

Comment: Did @CreativeKid kill his/her account?

Answer (score 4):

Deleting a popular question with good answers isn't really fair to the community.  I don't see anything problematic in your question; I certainly don't think you were being abusive.  Are you concerned about how you presented your question, like maybe your word choice?  You can edit to change that, so long as you don't change the question so much that you invalidate existing answers.

See [I've thought better of my question; can I delete it?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question) in the Help Center for other things you can do.

We want to work with you to find a solution that works for both you *and* the community.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I compleatly agree with you and I am not in anyways in a position to explain in better ways. The content is sensitive. (I am assuming that the diamond indicates Moderator.). If its in your level of system control I beg you please let it be deleated.

Comment: Is the problem that the question is tied to you?  It can be disconnected from your account (see the help).  That way we get to keep the question but it's not on your profile.

Answer (score 1):

You can flag your question for moderator attention by clicking on the little grey "flag" link under your post and then choosing "in need of moderator intervention". A little box will pop up that will allow you to explain your intentions to the moderator handling your flag. Mods generally know what to do in such cases and can help you.

But you have a couple options here, though it depends on how the moderator or SE staff member perceives your request:

1. Disassociate yourself from the question using the "Contact" form

It is possible to disassociate yourself from a post so that your name will not be mentioned together with the question. It will not display on your profile anymore and instead a "community" user will own it. More information can be found on MSE: 
[How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC BY-SA 3.0?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732/352819)

Basically you click on the "Contact" link at the bottom of the page and describe why you would like to be disassociated from the post.

Your name will still pop up in chat messages or comments that have mentioned you, so it won't necessarily bring you the kind of anonymity you want. This meta post for example will still point to it. But it would probably help if your goal is to be less visible.

2. Ask a mod with a mod flag for deletion

The question, together with all provided answers, can be deleted by a mod. Though it won't really be deleted. It will still be visible for everyone with more than 10k reputation once the site graduates. Currently 2k reputation is enough to see deleted posts. It could also get undeleted. By deleting the post lots of people will be affected. Everyone who had an answer there with upvotes will lose reputation. As the question wasn't closed the community seems to think that your question is generally useful for other people, so removing it will remove valuable content from the site. This is something to keep in mind that might very well make a moderator say "No" to your request.

Comment: I tried the delete button but it is asking for a further vote so I felt not to attract further attention....so requesting it here.

Comment: @CreativeKid Like I said you need a mod to delete it because a lot of people have interacted with the question and tried to help you with the problem you described. That's why the system prevents you from deleting it. Disassociating yourself is probably your safest bet, but you need to provide a good reason for why you want that. And if you really want to try and ask a moderator to delete your question the best way to contact them is to flag your post with a "in need of moderator attention" flag.

Comment: Ok will try that ways...thanks.

Comment: *"Ask a mod with a mod flag for deletion"* Yes, a diamond moderator technically can override the system-imposed limits on when a question can be deleted. However, [standard policy is to decline such flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5222/157730) (see under "If I flag my question with a request to delete it, what will happen?").

Comment: @Secespitus: You do not "need a good reason for why you want [dissociation]." The Creative Commons license gives you an absolute right to dissociation with no explanation required. If SE for some bizarre reason tries to refuse your dissociation request, your next step should be a DMCA takedown notice as a copyright violation (they broke the license).